# How to Integrate whatsapp api with c# wpf windows application pc

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on windows application (wpf c#), in which i have to integrate whatsapp api. So that i can post images in whatsapp using the windows application

I googled about integrating whatsapp api with c# wpf, but didnt find a proper solution.

Can you please guide me about how to integrate whatsapps with c# wpf application or provide with some useful links

Comment: Whatsapp does not have a public API. In fact they actively try to stop you from connecting to their network.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only possible way is to build an android application to listen to your C# software and post to WhatsApp.

You can create a virtual Android OS installed on the server, and install WhatsApp and your customized application on it.

In other words, the Android application will act as an intermediate layer between the C# and WhatsApp.

Please check the following link to help you integrate your Android Application with WhatsApp:

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

Regards,